# Which path must use for additional data with testdroid?

Tags: android, calabash-android, testdroid

Which path must  use for additional data like an image to be used in a backdoor method in Android.

I am using the public directory for example.

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Files are extracted directly to `/sdcard/` preserving the file structure you had in uploaded zip file.